# how to build hxselect with mingw?

Tags: html, makefile, mingw

I downloaded html-xml-utils-6.5.tar.gz and started compiling hxselect.c with mingw.  I need a makefile, but the package is designed to generate the makefile.  The build instructions are in a configure script, config.h.in file and makefile.in.

Is there a mingw-compatible tool to help generate the makefile?  I am considering making a linux machine so I can run the configuration to get the generic makefile, and then bring that back for mingw to start chewing on...

Is there an easier way?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've downloaded and installed mingw from [1], launch the MinGW Shell 
from the start menu and then cd to directory containing the configure script and proceed as you typically do with autotools based projects:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

The purpose of MinGW is in fact to make available to Windows a minimalistic GNU environment (meaning shell and other tools) which allow you to work (mostly) as you would in an operating system with a full-fledged GNU userland (such as GNU/Linux). Occasionally it seems that MinGW is used to denote the windows port of the gcc compiler, but it should be empathized that MinGW actually denotes the Windows port of a (minimalistic) GNU environment.

[1] http://www.mingw.org/

Comment: Thank you for this.  I tried msys once several years ago, and did not see a use for it.  Now I understand.  I think I am about to level up !